# excel VBA concatenate function

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation

First, I'm new to programming VBA to excel so if this program makes no sense...here's to the learning curve.
I'm trying to concatenate a range from "BO1:BQ" & DLimportLastRow, where DLimportLastRow is the last row of a variable import that was just run before this code. I've done as much internet research as i can, but most of the concatenate codes i found make no sense to me so i can't modify them to meet my needs. The end goal is to concatenate BO1:BQ" & DLimportLastRow with each cell separated by a "," and fitting into one cell which is "AE" & LastRow, where LastRow is the next blank cell in "AE".

```
 DLimportLastRow = WorkEnd.Cells(WorkEnd.Rows.Count, "BO").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
 DLimportLastRow = "BQ" & DLimportLastRow

 i = 1

 Do Until IsEmpty(Range("BO" & i).Value) = True Or Range("C" & i).Value = "" Or Range("C" & i).Value = Null Or Range("C" & i).Value = 0
        x = Workbooks(WName).Worksheets("ReportGroupingInfo").Range("BO" & i).Value
        For Each cell In Range("BO1", DLimportLastRow)
              y = x & cell.Value & ","
              i = i + 1
        Next
 Loop
          
 Range("AE" & LastRow).Value = y
```

Comment: Each loop you overwrite `y` and only use it until the loop is over. You need to use the previous value of `y` inside the concatenation to prevent it from being overwritten

Comment: Do you really want to include all three columns in the concatenation??   **BO1:BQ99** or whatever **99** turns out to be??

Comment: Yes, i'd like to include all three column values because that's what i'm bring over from another workbook. I have over 100 workbooks to do this to.

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting closer but when i check the value of "y", it gives me 0. It is cycling through the range fine, but i'm not picking up any values.

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

Dim y as string

```
   i = 1
   Do Until IsEmpty(Range("BO" & i).Value) = True Or Range("C" & i).Value = "" Or Range("C" & i).Value = Null Or Range("C" & i).Value = 0
       For Each cell In Range("BO1", DLimportLastRow)
       y = y & cell.Value & ","
       i = i + 1
       Next
   Loop
      Range("AE" & LastRow).Value = y
```